# How to implement all format options in fillable forms using PDF BOX 2

Tags: java, pdfbox, fillable

I need to apply the below mentioned format properties on Acrobat DC to my text box fields.

[image: Format_Category]

Fields where created using below snippet,

```
private static void addTBField(PDAcroForm acroForm, PDPage page, String name, float x, float y, float width,
        float height, String toolTip, long fontSize, String fontFamily, long maxLength, Boolean required,
        Boolean multiLine, Boolean checkSpelling, Boolean scrollLongText, Boolean readOnly, Boolean combofChar) {

    try {
        
        PDTextField textBox = new PDTextField(acroForm);
        textBox.setPartialName(name);
        acroForm.getFields().add(textBox);

        
        PDAnnotationWidget widget = textBox.getWidgets().get(0);
        PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(x, y, width, height);
        widget.setRectangle(rect);
        widget.setPage(page);

        PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(
                new COSDictionary());
        if (checkSpelling) {
            checkSpelling = false;
        } else {
            checkSpelling = true;
        }
        if (scrollLongText) {
            scrollLongText = false;
        } else {
            scrollLongText = true;
        }

        widget.setPrinted(true);
        
        page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

        String defaultAppearanceString = "/" + fontFamily + " " + fontSize + " Tf 0 0 0 rg";
        textBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);
        textBox.setRequired(required);
        textBox.setAlternateFieldName(toolTip);
        textBox.setComb(combofChar);
        textBox.setDoNotSpellCheck(checkSpelling);
        textBox.setDoNotScroll(scrollLongText);
        textBox.setMaxLen((int) maxLength);
        textBox.setMultiline(multiLine);
        textBox.setQ(PDVariableText.QUADDING_LEFT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Need to implement all the format categories available in the above picture using the PDF Box. I am new to this pdf domain. Kindly share the details if any utility is already available inside PDF Box Library.

Comment: Any suggestion folks?

Comment: Do we have any utility in PDF Box for doing the above feature or any other logical ways available to implement it?

Comment: No, I suspect these formatting is done with Javascript. This isn't PDF, it's additional code from Adobe. Or it's PDF 2.0 which PDFBox doesn't really support.